# VLC adding extensions, remote connection, etc

Tags: android, networking, tcp, streaming, vlc

I have a question whether I can remotely control VLC video player program (play, pause, sound, maybe some video streaming, cam streaming) between my computer/mobile phone.

Here is my plan: 
1. VLC player on Mac OS 
2. writing some TCP Server (C++)
3. writing client on side of android mobile phone
   here i consider writing in C++ in order to use it in android/ios ? 
4. writing application on Android with simple buttons that can control remotely this player... 
Can this solution work properly?

Some additional questions: 
1. Can such solution work over WAN (Internet) not only LAN (TCP socket communication) 
2. VLC player has in preferences Interface > Main Interfaces > RC
   and Lua HTTP, Lua Telnet, etc. (whats the aim of this? ) 
3. I saw some application on Google Store that comunicates via Lua HTTP?

4. I would prefer writing my own server/client + protocol for communication this is for university lower degree project. 
   So my question is whether if I will write such a server, Will there be possibility to integrate it with VLC somehow like adding to preferences > Interfeaces, or it should be separate program or it can be written as plugin or some add-on ?

In summary I need some help to direct me which solution will be the best to provide the most seamless interaction with VLC and have own server, client, protocol in order it hasn't been to easy (I saw in documentacion that possibly there are simple commands in VLC over HTTP protocol which I assume could allow for easy interacting with VLC).

I think also about extending this project by enabling mouse move control on Mac OS / Windows. What should I need for it?

The last part is to enable streaming video to phone and maybe in opposite direction from phone to VLC player. Also web cam capture streaming from phone to VLC and oposite Mac book to phone will be interesting solution.?

thanks for any help

PLEASE If it is too long question please concentrate on answering whether it is possible to do, and whether it can be seamlessly integrated in such way that end user shouldn't have to make many hours of configuration... 
Best solution form my point of view:
- preference screen of my plugin embedded in VLC player settings 
- writing TCP port/ host (maybe using current host IP in local network) 
- on mobile side detecting and connecting via this host:port using client and it just works...

Answer (score 0):

*1. VLC player on Mac OS 2. writing some TCP Server (C++) 3. writing client on side of android mobile phone here i consider writing in C++ in order to use it in android/ios ? 4. writing application on Android with simple buttons that can control remotely this player... Can this solution work properly?*

Yes it is possible and it works perfectly. VLC has in built server, so you do not need another server app to control it. you just write a client side app for android or Windows/iOS. However if you still want to write server app, you can do so (I don't recommend it), but obviously communication delay between client app and VLC is higher than usual.

*1. Can such solution work over WAN (Internet) not only LAN (TCP socket communication) 2. VLC player has in preferences Interface > Main Interfaces > RC
and Lua HTTP, Lua Telnet, etc. (whats the aim of this? ) 3. I saw some application on Google Store that comunicates via Lua HTTP?*

Yes it should be possible, but I haven't tried it though.

*I would prefer writing my own server/client + protocol for communication this is for university lower degree project. So my question is whether if I will write such a server, Will there be possibility to integrate it with VLC somehow like adding to preferences > Interfeaces, or it should be separate program or it can be written as plugin or some add-on ?*

As I said, you can write your own server app, you can integrate that server with VLC server (web Interface). Again this method is not recommended. 
If you still want to write server app, instead of integrating with VLC's web interface, map key board short cuts (for example, receive stop request from your client app, and rise keyboard 'S' key event on your server app. 'S' key is short cut for stop command for VLC. For more VLC short cut keys refer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/196371/master-vlc-with-these-23-keyboard-shortcuts/))

**VLC supports both transcoding and streaming, I suggest you to write only client app, integrate it with the VLC Web interface. That is the best method.** (For more info, there are many apps on play store, try any one of them or refer VLC forum)

Comment: I prefer writing my own server... couldn't I write some plugin/extension which somehow modify VLC and can call some suitable functions directly like stopPlaying(), startPlaying(), etc.?

Comment: could you give me some link where in documantation is such possibility:
It will be in this way:
1. in VLC user download plugin and in preferences there is screen to configure my plugin as normal plugin
or
2. user download my server program and it has possibility to modify working VLC directly calling some functions from it ?

Comment: I haven't worked on any VLC plugin, but you can find most of the resources on https://wiki.videolan.org/.